# What should I define for Template in cloud formation section for codepipeline?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am currently working on aws codepipeline. I built a stack with template for lambda function. In codepipeline deploy stage, with cloudformation, what should I give value for Template which is asking value in format inputArtifactName::TemplateFileName? what should be the inputArtifactName and TemplateFileName? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Here what I have done to solve my problem. I made a zip file which includes the template.json and configuration for template which is also a json file. And I put the output artifact name from source in the pipeline as the input artifact name for deploy stage.

Comment: the `InputArtifact` of the Deploy-Stage is the `OutputArtifact` of the Source- or Build-Stage.

Answer (score 0):

The inputArtifactName is the outputArtifactName you specify in previous source or build stage. And the TemplateFileName is the CloudFormation template file in the input artifact that you want to deploy. A input artifact may have multiple CloudFormation templates. You may want to take a look at a complete walkthrough https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-basic-walkthrough.html